# How can I solve the CORS error when trying to access a folder on server using. net core API

Tags: c#, .net, http, iis

I am able to upload images to a folder on my server without any issues. When I want to access it I get the same folder I get a CORS error. I am using IIS 10 and my application is in .net core API

```
using PortalApp.Contracts.Data.Dtos.Custom;
using PortalApp.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

builder.Services.AddOptions<AppPortalSettings>().BindConfiguration("AppPortalSettings");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppPortalDatabaseContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppPortalDatabaseContext>();
builder.Services.AddCustomServices();
builder.Services.AddMapper();
builder.Services.AddCors();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    var key = builder.Configuration["AppPortalSettings:Key"];
    var issuer = builder.Configuration["AppPortalSettings:Issuer"];
    var audience = builder.Configuration["AppPortalSettings:Issuer"];

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidIssuer = issuer,
        ValidAudience = audience,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))
    };
});
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{

    options.AddPolicy(name:"Policy1",
       builder =>
        {
            builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => new Uri(origin).Host == "localhost")
                .AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();

        });

    options.AddPolicy("MyCorsPolicy",
       builder => builder
          .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
          .WithOrigins("https://*.", "http://*.")
          .AllowAnyMethod()
          .AllowCredentials()
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          .Build()
       );
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
      builder => builder
         .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
         .WithOrigins("http://15x.xxx.xxx.xxx:6065/", "http://*.")
         .AllowAnyMethod()
         .AllowCredentials()
         .AllowAnyHeader()
         .Build()
      );

});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache(); 

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
#region Use Static Files
try
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Uploads")),
    RequestPath = "/Uploads"
});
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
}
#endregion
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors();
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization(); 
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Web Config On The Server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
    <modules> 
          <remove name="WebDAVModule" /> 
         </modules> 
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
         </handlers>        
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\App.Api.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess"/>
   

    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: f75f628c-d8f8-41eb-b53c-9b9ec6e5a000-->
```

Comment: Can you please post your full setup somewhere like github? Because currently you have strange mixed ordering (like using builder after app was build and used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [`UseCors` and `UseStaticFiles` order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0#usecors-and-usestaticfiles-order) section of the docs:

> Typically, `UseStaticFiles` is called before `UseCors`. Apps that use JavaScript to retrieve static files cross site must call `UseCors` before `UseStaticFiles`.

If other CORS request work then it seems that it is your case, so you can try changing the middleware order:

```
app.UseCors(x => ...);
app.UseStaticFiles(...);
```

Or you can try leveraging the `OnPrepareResponse` property of `StaticFileOptions` to apply the CORS:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx => {
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
            "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    }
});
```

Or by using [solution from this blog post](https://www.bytefish.de/blog/aspnetcore_static_files_cors.html#the-solution):

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
    OnPrepareResponse = (ctx) =>
    {
        var policy = corsPolicyProvider.GetPolicyAsync(ctx.Context, "CorsPolicyName")
            .ConfigureAwait(false)
            .GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        var corsResult = corsService.EvaluatePolicy(ctx.Context, policy);

        corsService.ApplyResult(corsResult, ctx.Context.Response);
    }
});
```

P.S.

Also in general you should avoid `AllowAnyOrigin` (though maybe it is just part of you attempts to solve the issue).